# How to update rows in SnowFlake using a for-loop

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this table in SnowFlake:

[image]

What I want to do is to incrementally update the `row_id` by `internal_id`. E.g. for `internal_id = CHE20220708134003004472`, the row_id should take the values from 1 to 3 respectively, and so on for the other ids.

Here is an example of the desired output:

[image]

I've tried to do that by using the following code:

```
execute immediate $$
declare
  counter integer default 1;
  total_rows integer default (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "DB_MX_DEV"."STAGING"."stg_chedraui_inv_day" WHERE internall_id = 'CHE20220708134003004472');
begin
  for i in 1 to total_rows do
    counter := counter + 1;
    UPDATE "DB_MX_DEV"."STAGING"."stg_chedraui_inv_day" SET row_id = counter where internall_id = 'CHE20220708134003004472';
  end for;
  return counter;
end;
$$;
```

However, I got this error:
`Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 8 at position 4 : SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 65 invalid identifier 'COUNTER'`

Note: At the moment, the code above is only trying to update the `row_id` for a specific `internal_id`, I'm still trying to figure out how to do it for all ids.

Comment: I know the question is asking to do this in a loop - but please, consider doing this NOT on a loop. Do just one large `UPDATE` statement, and set the ids using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I actually can't figure out how to do this via an update join, mainly because there is no actual PK in the OP's starting table.  If you know of a way, you should post an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen overwrite would work?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *not* even doing this update.  Instead, to view your data this way, just use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```sql
SELECT INTERNALL_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INTERNALL_ID ORDER BY INTERNALL_ID) ROW_ID
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Not what I want. I need to do the update.

Answer (score 0):

How about an `OVERWRITE` to replace all the previous rows, with the rows generated by Tim's solution:

```sql
insert OVERWRITE into update_me
select id, row_number() over(partition by id order by row_id) row_id
from update_me
```

---

Data setup:

```sql
create or replace temp table update_me as

select $1 id, null::number row_id
from values('a'),('a'),('a'),('b'),('b')
```